# Android library with 3rd party transitive dependencies with Artifactory

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to get my android library to work in Artifactory. I followed this post http://jeroenmols.com/blog/2015/08/13/artifactory2/ to publish the library on a local artifactory server. Everything works and I get both the aar & the pom file built and uploaded but the problem is I can't get any of the transitive dependencies to resolve. For example my library depends on volley and I want to avoid having to redeclare the volley dependency in my app but also be able to use some of volleys classes. 
If I do the following on local maven repo this fixes this for me and I get to use the dependencies transitively.

```
mvn-install ... -DpomFile=library.pom
```

But with artifactory my app complains about not having those dependencies and I have to redeclare them in the apps build.gradle file. 
What do I have to do to get the same behavior as the -DpomFile flag in artifactory?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had deployed the same version with an incorrect pom file and this was cached in my project. I had to run `./gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies` for the new pom file to work.